How to change the PATH of VS extension?
I installed some extensions on VisualStudio but it seems they weren't installed in the correct PATH so I can't use them through VS.
I keep getting this message: The term 'pyfiglet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check if you spelled the name correctly, or if a path was included, check that the path is correct and try again.
It does not only happen with pyfiglet, also does it with pytest, pip3 and all the extensions I downloaded after installing Python library.
I searched on the file explorer and found them inside Python folder, however if I move the documents it doesn't work either.
I do not know which is the correct PATH or how to solve this. Help :(
Tried to move the documents into visualcode folder manually, tried unistalling it and doing it all again but sill appears on what seems to be the wrong foler.
Never happened before and I've been using VS for a year now having different extensions.

you are not talking about VSC extension but Python external modules

make sure you have the correct virtual environment active when using pip

try using a cmd terminal

This has nothing to do with python extensions. You need to know which environment your packages are installed in and which environment your terminal is using.
My suggestion is to create virtual environments for each workspace to make it easier to manage packages and execute scripts.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command
